# Check if elements of a Char Array appear in another Char Array

Tags: c#, arrays, char

I'm working on a problem where I have two Char Arrays, something like the following:


cArray1 = ['p', 'a', 'n', 'd', 'a']

cArray2 = ['a', 'v', 'd', 'e', 'r', 'e', 'n', 'j', 'j', 'a', 'v', 'h', 'v', 'p']

I need to check if all elements of cArray1 are present in cArray2. I wrote a solution in C# using Linq:

`var found = cArray1.Select(c => char.ToUpper(c)).Distinct().All(c => cArray2.Contains(c))`

The above logic works fine in most cases, but the 'Distinct' command is causing some issues. If we consider both arrays that I have mentioned here, then 'found' should be 'true' Only if the characters [p, a, n, d, a] appear in cArray2. But right now, I get a 'true' for [p, a, n, d] because of the 'Distinct'.

Comment: `var found = cArray1.GroupBy(c1 => c1).All(g => cArray2.Count(c2 => c2 == g.Key) >= g.Count())` ?

Comment: Yes.. this worked as well. Thank you so much !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var found = cArray1.All(x => cArray1.Count(y => y == x) <= cArray2.Count(y => y == x));
```

Comment: Oh this Worked!! Thank you so much !